# Most Efficient way to Add Multiple Children to Parent by ID in Many to Many in Entity Framework Application (create multiple mappings)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, database-performance

Take the code in this example:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

What would be the most efficient way to add multiple courses to a student when I have the course IDs?

So, for example, the function may look like this:

```
 private static void AddCoursesToStudent(SchoolDBContext context, Student student, List<int> CourseIds)
    {}
```

And my current attempt looks like this:

```
public static async Task AddCoursesToStudentAsync(SchoolDBContext context, Student student, List<int> CourseIds)
    {
        await context.Courses.Where(x => CourseIds.Contains(x.CourseId)).ForEachAsync(x => x.Students.Add(student));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static void AddCoursesToStudent(SchoolDBContext context, Student student, List<int> CourseIds)
    {
        var task = AddCoursesToStudentAsync(context,student,CourseIds);
        task.Wait();
    }
```

Which works, but seems a bit sloppy, especially mixing in the async. I am also thinking the "Where" combined with the "ForEach" will pull up all the records somewhere.

In other projects where it wasn't code first we would usually have a manually created "MappingTable" which in this case would look like:

```
public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key] [Column(Order = 0)]
    private int StudentId;
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    private int CourseId;

    public StudentCourse(int courseIde, int studentId)
    {
        StudentId = studentId;
        CourseId = courseIde;
    }
}
```

And you would go something like:

```
 public static  void AddCoursesToStudentMaps(SchoolDBContext context, Student student, List<int> CourseIds)
    {
        List<StudentCourse> maps = CourseIds.ConvertAll(courseId => new StudentCourse(courseId, student.StudentId)).ToList();
        context.StudentCourses.AddRange(maps);
    }
```

It would be nice to do this in a way that Entity Framework manages this, perhaps I could just create the student Courses class and add it to the context? But that seems to defeat the point, especially as we have a lot of many to many and having EF create the mapping table for us would cut down the code. I just think if EF is capable of creating the mapping automatically, it must have a way of efficiently creating new links without redoing the work it has done?

In order to test this I have created this example code, with a lazy setup function, so if anyone wants to have a bash, this should get you up and running:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    private static void Run()
    {
        using (SchoolDBContext context = new SchoolDBContext())
        {
            /* Run once
             * SetUp(context);
             */
            Test(context);
            Output(context);
        }
    }

    static void SetUp(SchoolDBContext context)
    {
        context.Students.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Gerry" });
        context.Students.Add( new Student() { StudentName = "Bob" }  );
        context.Students.Add( new Student() { StudentName = "Jane" } );

        context.Courses.Add( new Course() { CourseName = "Science" });
        context.Courses.Add( new Course() { CourseName = "Math" }  );
        context.Courses.Add( new Course() { CourseName = "History" } );
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "Other History" });
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "Roman History" });
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "English History" });
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "Super History" });
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "Tudor History" });
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "Queen History" });
        context.Courses.Add(new Course() { CourseName = "King History" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void Test(SchoolDBContext context)
    {

        var ids = context.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseName.Contains("History")).Select(x => x.CourseId).ToList();
        var student = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StudentName == "Bob");
        AddCoursesToStudent(context, student, ids);
    }

    private static void Output(SchoolDBContext context)
    {
        OutputStudents(context);
    }

    private static void OutputStudents(SchoolDBContext context)
    {
        var allStudents = context.Students.ToList();
        foreach (var student in allStudents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Student: {student.StudentName}");
            if (student.Courses.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("is enrolled on");
                Console.WriteLine("**************************");
                foreach (var contextCourseStudent in student.Courses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("     " + contextCourseStudent.CourseName);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("************************ ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void OutputCourse(SchoolDBContext context)
```

p.s. the reason for not just having a list of courses is due to the fact we have forms/apps etc already set up that send id lists and as mentioned it seems silly and inefficient to then pull those models out of the database, purely to add them to the parent.

Comment: Your question has too much text for such a simple question. Also, if you need to have the list of students each course has, how do you expect to get it without actually going to the database to get that course? That's why many-to-many relationships are always modeled with a third entity.

Comment: Apologies, I just wanted to show working, but clearly its misleading as you misunderstood my question, I dont need the courses, I already have the course ids and just want to add the "link" which as you say is typically modelled with a third entity, but EF can helpfully create said link table 'under the hood' but in my specific case unless I ignore EFs built in ability and create my own third entity, it seems inefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `many-to-many` with implicit link table is Code First specific. Also while it makes querying easier and more natural, as you already have seen it has obvious drawbacks when with link modifications.

It's possible to implement the adding new links efficiently by using *stub entities*:

```
static void AddCoursesToStudent(SchoolDBContext context, Student student, List<int> CourseIds)
{
    student.Courses = CourseIds.Select(id => context.Courses.Attach(new Course { CourseId = id })).ToList();
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works, but under the following constraints:

(1) The `context` has been created specifically for this call
(2) `student` is already attached to the `context`
(3) All the `CourseIds` exist in the database
(4) There are no `Course` entities loaded in the context with some of the `CourseIds`
(5) The initial `student.Courses` collection is not eager or lazy loaded. This is specifically to enforce *add link* operation (vs *replace all links* by determining the added and removed items)
(6) You don't use afterwards the `context` or any of the `Course` objects, because all their properties except the PK are not real.

An example considering all the constraints:

```
public void AddCoursesToStudent(int studentId, List<int> coursesIds)
{
    using (var context = new SchoolDBContext())
    {
        var student = context.Students.Find(studentId);
        AddCoursesToStudent(context, student, coursesIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering (might be way off), but isn't this for a one-to-many relationship? I am not sure how EF does this internally, but how is it that adding the many to one side (i.e assigning the courses to the student) adds the many to the other side (i.e assigning the new student to each course)?

Comment: 1 - so for example the context is within a using block, how would this work on a web project?

Comment: 2- by this do you mean the student exists within the DB already, or has been modified in this context / specifically pulled out from *this* context

Comment: 5 - can you provide links to how to set up in the different ways, or to answer 1,2 & 5 provide an example within a using block for a web style db :)

Comment: silly me I assumed any loading settings be put into the constructor/set up directly after

Comment: @chrispepper1989 It works with typical Web controller actions which allocate db context, do something and dispose it (or within a `using` block as you mentioned). It doesn't work for long lived context used for many operations.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No, this trick is for many-to-many. You could use the `IColection<T>` navigation property of any of the two sides to add a link to the other side. The `Attach` is used to tell EF that the `Course` is an existing (otherwise it will try to add both new `Course` and link). And thanks for the edit, appreciate!